# Complete override of error handler in PlayFramework

Tags: playframework

When an unexpected exception is generated in a Play application, you can override the response in `Global.onError()`. However, the exception still seems to get written as an ERROR log by Play. Is there any way to override that behaviour (only for specific exceptions)?

Case explanation: Generally the response to an unexpected exception from an API call would be an error page, in which case it's perfectly ok to also log it as an error. However, some very specific API exceptions might result just in a redirect to the logout page, for example, if the session has expired, or the the user was forced logged out by an admin. In these cases I would not want the API exception to be logged as an error. It would be a WARN at best. I could of course treat that case in every single place where I make an API call but that's a daunting perspective. A global error handler seems a much better place to put this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that you can change the way it is used, but Play will always log it as an error [before it gives control over the error](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/YSASFRpATTQ). But you still will be able to change the response depending on the exception that has been thrown.

```
override def onError(request: RequestHeader, ex: Throwable) = {
  Future.successful(InternalServerError(
    views.html.errorPage(ex)
  ))
}
```

If you would like to read more about how to change this behaviour or others, you can have a look [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaGlobal).

**EDIT**

As @cristian-vrabie mention in the comments, we can use *action composition* to get control over an action behaviour without being intrusive. We will need to declare a function that gets an Action that will be transformed into the result.

```
import play.api.mvc._

case class Logging[A](action: Action[A]) extends Action[A] {
  def apply(request: Request[A]): Future[SimpleResult] = {
    Logger.info("Calling action")
    action(request)
  }

  lazy val parser = action.parser
}
```

You can have a look at [this link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaActionsComposition) or [this link](http://engineering.linkedin.com/play/play-framework-democratizing-functional-programming-modern-web-programmers) for more information about it.

Comment: Ah, the linked thread does mention that this [should be done through Action composition](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/YSASFRpATTQ/iP_3XA6urkwJ). Since I already do this for logged in checks it's trivial to move the redirect to wrap the block invocation as a recover on relevant exceptions. This will completely drop the exception so it will not trigger a log.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to hint at this? It might be more useful for other people, and I'll accept it as the solution.

Comment: Sure. Good to know that it is helpful. I will update my answer to make it more useful.

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer in case you need it is not clear enough (or if I missed the point)